# Trying to parse a mongoose object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

So I'm calling mongodb and I'm having trouble parsing the data so I can pass it to the view. I wrote front end in EJS.

This is the model I'm calling:

```
const CourseworkSchema = new Schema({
assignment: [
    {
        type: String
    }
],
author: {
    id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    name: String
}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Coursework', CourseworkSchema);
```

Here is the route in which I'm calling the Corsework:

```
app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    if(req.user.isTeacher) {
        // render dashboard for teacher
        //let author = author._id
        let arr = Coursework.find({  })
        //console.log(arr)
        let val = JSON.stringify(arr.assignment)
        //console.log(val)
        console.log(arr.assignment)
        res.render('instructor', {arr: val, isAuth:req.isAuthenticated()})
    }else {
        // render dashboard for student
        res.render('student', {isAuth: req.isAuthenticated()})
    }
}
```

I need to use an assignment in the view.
Every time I try to stringify it comes up as `undefined`.
How can I parse it so I can use the properties `author` and `assigment`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line `let arr = Coursework.find({  })` returns an array of documents. You have to iterate over the `arr` to get the particular assignment and simple `arr.assignment` won't work

e.g

```
let arr = await Coursework.find({  })
for (const doc of arr) {
    console.log(doc.assignment);
    console.log(doc.author);
}
```

As you can see in the following code snippet i create two CourseWork items and then Iterate over them to log them to console

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

run().catch(error => console.log(error.stack));

async function run() {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', { useNewUrlParser: true });
    await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();

    const CourseworkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    assignment: [
        {
            type: String
        }
    ],
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        name: String
    }
    });

    const CourseWork = mongoose.model('Coursework', CourseworkSchema);

    await CourseWork.create({ assignment: "first assignment", author: { name: "first author" }});
    await CourseWork.create({ assignment: "Second assignment", author: { name: "second author" }});

    const docs = await CourseWork.find();
    console.log(docs);

    for (const doc of docs) {
        console.log(doc.assignment);
        console.log(doc.author);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
app.get('/dashboard', async (req, res) => {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        if(req.user.isTeacher) {
            // render dashboard for teacher
            //let author = author._id
            let arr = await Coursework.find({}).lean(true).exec();
            //console.log(arr)
            /** 
              * As `.find()` returns an array & to access `assignment` field on each doc, You need to iterate over.
              * let val = JSON.stringify(arr.assignment) has to be replaced
              */
            let val = arr.map((i)=> {return JSON.stringify(i.assignment)}) // will be an array of parsed `assignment` values
            //console.log(val)
            res.render('instructor', {arr: val, isAuth:req.isAuthenticated()})
        }else {
            // render dashboard for student
            res.render('student', {isAuth: req.isAuthenticated()})
        }
    }
```

As Node.Js is asynchronous, it doesn't wait until DB operation `Coursework.find({})` is done. So you need to wait until DB find call is done & then `arr` will be populated with data & also for just printing we don't need to use `.lean()` but if you want to alter/manipulate fields inside returned document then you've to convert mongoose documents to .Js objects for further usage. In addition, you need to wrap this code in `try-catch` block as it's recommended to wrap `async` functions in try catch.

**Note :** If you're checking for an `author` using `author._id` - kind of filtering on unique field then try to use `.findOne()` which will return either `null` or a matched document, that helps us to avoid un-necessary iteration over an array.

Comment: it was still undefined

Comment: @RockySingh : ohh my bad, I've overlooked & only checked `console.log(arr)` but didn't look into `let val = JSON.stringify(arr.assignment)`, updated my answer for all scenarios..